# SQLCipher build failed without error

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

I am trying to add SQLCipher to a project, but SQLCipher failed without an issue.
I am following the tutorial here: http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/

Xcode: 4.6.2
SQLCipher: 3.7.14.1
OpenSSL: 1.0.1e

If there anyone with a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some tangible details on what errors / problems you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You can build static libraries separately for SQLCipher and OpenSSL. This saves tons of build time

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17462101/2369266